How to represent a point's velocity seen from a moving coordinate system?
let us consider a three-dimensional point $x$ that is fixed in the world coordinate system, ie. its velocity is zero, $\dot{x}=0$.
Consider another coordinate system that is defined by a rotation matrix $R$ and a translation vector $t$.
If I am not mistaken, we can project the point $x$ into the new coordinate system through
$$
x' = R^T (x - t)
$$
In my case, this new coordinate system is moving, hence, both $R$ and $t$ are not constant over time. This motion is specified by a six-dimensional twist combining linear velocity $v$ and angular velocity $w$.
Then, seen from this new (moving) coordinate system, the projected point will have a non-zero velocity $\dot{x}' \neq 0$.
Question: How can I express $\dot{x}'$ in terms of $v$ and $w$?
I need an expression in this form:
$$
\dot{x}' = A \begin{bmatrix}v \\ w \end{bmatrix}
$$
What is this matrix $A$? It should be somehow related to the adjoint matrix. I tried to compute the derivative of $x' = R^T (x - t)$, however this didn't work out...
Bonus: The problem becomes even more difficult when the point $x$ is also moving in the world coordinate system with $\dot{x} \neq 0$ ... Any ideas in this direction?
Thanks for your support
